# How to SELECT titles by sales, where sales less than N?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables: `titles` and `sales` created by queries:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sales] 
(
    [stor_id] [char] (4) NOT NULL,
    [ord_num] [varchar] (20) NOT NULL,
    [ord_date] [datetime] NOT NULL, 
    [qty] [smallint] NOT NULL, --quantity of sold books in this transaction
    [payterms] varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    [title_id] varchar(6) NOT NULL, --FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES titles(title_id),

    CONSTRAINT FK_S_title_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (title_id) REFERENCES titles(title_id),
    CONSTRAINT PK_sales 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (stor_id, ord_num, title_id)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[titles] 
(
    [title_id] varchar(6) CONSTRAINT PK_titles PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [title] varchar(80) NOT NULL, --name of book
    [type] char(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('UNDECIDED'),
    [pub_id] char(4) NULL,
    [price] money NULL,
    [advance] money NULL,
    [royalty] int NULL,
    [ytd_sales] int NULL,
    [notes] varchar(200) NULL,
    [pubdate] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I know that I can get a table of pairs `title` and `sumOfSales` by this query

```
SELECT title, SUM(qty) AS sumOfSales 
FROM titles AS t, sales AS s
WHERE t.title_id = s.title_id 
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY title
```

It results as this:

[image]

But I need to select all titles that are sold less or equal than 10 times and get something like this, without `qty` (nor `sumOfSales`) column:

```
title 
=======================================
ABookThatIsSoldLessOrEqual10Times
NameOfAnotherBookSoldLessOrEqual10times
NameOfBookSoldLessOrEqual10times
```

EDIT: Thank you for answers. I wanted to use `HAVING`, but it doesn't do what I need to have in result of `SELECT`. I need to have a list of just titles of books that are sold only 10 or less times.

I could use a temporary table and do 2 `SELECT`s instead of one. But it is not very good practice.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS you need to show a list of just titles of books then try this:

```
SELECT title FROM titles AS t inner join sale AS s
on t.title_id = s.title_id 
GROUP BY title
HAVING sum(qty) <= 10 
ORDER BY title
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT title, SUM(qty) AS sumOfSales
FROM titles AS t, sales AS s
WHERE t.title_id = s.title_id 
GROUP BY title
HAVING SUM(qty) < 11
ORDER BY title
```

You can write the condition as `SUM(qty) <= 10` if you like, but I find `SUM(qty) < 11` more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add HAVING to your query

```
SELECT title, sum(qty) AS sumOfSales 
FROM 
    titles AS t
    INNER JOIN sales AS s ON t.title_id = s.title_id 
GROUP BY title
HAVING sum(qty) <= 10 
ORDER BY title
```